# Need help to pass Account Id as parameter of Command Link

Tags: visualforce, parameters, commandlink

I have a VF Page Account Detail hich displays list of account Names. The account Names are command link and clicking on the link redirects to another page which displays the account Id.

I have written below code but the Account Id parameter does not pass to assign To Parameter

This looks like a very sinple code but i  am missing something.

Please help.

VF Page: AccountDetails

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" id="Page" extensions="AccountDetailController">

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="Accountlist" title="AccBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockTable title="Account List Table" value="{!listAccount}" var="a" id="acclisttable" rows="10">
            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                <apex:commandLink action="{!getContact}" value="{!a.name}">
                    <apex:param name='acc' value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!accId}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                <apex:outputText>{!a.id}</apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Apex Class  :AccountDetailController

```
public class AccountDetailController {
public List<Account> AccAll {get;set;}
public List<Account> listAccount {get;set;}
public List<Account> acclist {get;set;}
Integer TotalRecs;
List<Contact> Listcon {get;set;}
Integer blocksize =10;
integer index=0;
String pg;
public Id accId {get;set;}

public AccountDetailController(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller){

    AccAll=[select id,Name from Account];
    listAccount=getAccounts();
    TotalRecs=AccAll.size();
    //accId='jofijO';

}

Public List<Account> getAccounts(){

    acclist=[select id,Name from Account Limit :blocksize OFFSET :index];

    return acclist;

}

public PageReference getContact(){

    Id accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accId');
    System.debug('accId'+accId);
    System.debug('accountId'+accountId);
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/ContactDetail');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    /*pg= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    System.debug('debug'+pg);
    if(pg != null){
        PageReference pageRef1 = new PageReference('/apex/ContactDetail');
        pageRef1.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef1;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }*/
}
```

}

VF Page : ContactDetails

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="AccountDetailController">
<apex:pageBlock id="ConBlock">

    <apex:outputText >{!accId}</apex:outputText>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set redirect to true, or when the standard controller and/or extensions do not match, the view state is cleared on the next page.

## Option 1

Change the ContactDetail page's first line:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountDetailController">
```

And do not set the redirect flag:

```
return Page.ContactDetail;
```

## Option 2

Set the parameter on the page reference. You'll need to load it in the page's constructor:

```
PageReference ref = Page.ContactDetail;
ref.getParameters().put('accId', accid);
return ref.setRedirect(true);
```

Comment: I may be missing something here but can't this be done with a `URLFOR($Page.ContactDetail,null,[accId=a.Id])` on the account list page and `$CurrentPage.parameters.accid` on the detail page?

Comment: @cropredy you're right. I was just approaching this from the Apex side, but a vf expression would also work.